# How to Resize the Window in JQuery method Windows Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to Resize the window which is outcome of JQuery Method Windows.Prompt?

Here is my Function:

```
  function copyToClipboard(text) {
      window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
  }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<td><button id="demo" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML )">This is what I want to copy</button>
```

Comment: Have a visit to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp), all window object are nicely explained here. Hope this link is upto your expectation and meets your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not modify or resize the prompt window. It is similar to the alert boxes which are controlled by browser. There are standards of prompt boxes which has security reasons so that you can't make a JavaScript prompt look like something else in an attempt to trick the user.

I would suggest to use jQuery UI to accomplish similar functionality which will give you better control on UI side. Here is the e.g. of JQuery UI dialog box https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Hope this helps to you.